# Parse and extract a value from streaming XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

After much ado, I managed to create a restful service in asp.net MVC following [Omar's brilliant Restful Asp.net article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Build-truly-RESTful-API-194a6253)

Just one little thing remains.

My Asp.Net MVC controller returns an XML file , which has this tag

```
< FileCode > 24233224< / FileCode >
```

This is a console application I use to send a Get request which gives me **the whole** Xml file

```
        //Generate get request
        string url = "http://localhost:1193/Home/index?File=343456789012286";
        HttpWebRequest GETRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        GETRequest.Method = "GET";
        GETRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
        GETRequest.Accept = "text/xml";

        Console.WriteLine("Sending GET Request");
        HttpWebResponse GETResponse = (HttpWebResponse)GETRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream GETResponseStream = GETResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GETResponseStream);

        Console.WriteLine("Response from Server");

       // This writes whole file on screen
       Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

I *could* perhaps save this file and then use Linq to parse it, but can't I just get the value in my  tag out without saving it ? I simply need the **FileCode**

Thankyou :)

Comment: Have you tried XmlReader? The api isn't hugely "obvious",  it it'll do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo could emply the [XPathReader (source download)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22677).

It comes with source and testsuite.

What it gives you is the ability to work with highlevel query constructs (XPath) in streaming mode.

---

There is also a similar article on CodeProject: [Fast screen scraping with XPath over a modified XmlTextReader and SgmlReader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18740/Fast-screen-scraping-with-XPath-over-a-modified-Xm)

Comment: I actually ended up using XmlDocument 's LoadXml() and that worked, but that XPathReader looks interesting, I'd look into it later. thanks